Excel: Print exact name found from the list for exact date
Let's say I have a table with dates (all the calendar dates for 2024) and names (divided into columns):
AllNames



Date
Names






01 Jan
Aaa
Bbb
Vvv


02 Jan
Ccc




03 Jan
Ddd





I also have a list of some employee' names (current employees, names can be changed in future):
employees



Employees




Aaa


Vvv


Ccc



I would like to check if employee from the sheet Employees ("Aaa" for example) is in the AllNames sheet/table for an exact date. And if so, then print their name (or multiple names if several employees found for that date) near to that date:
calendar



Date
Math?




01 Jan
Aaa, Vvv


02 Jan
Ccc


03 Jan
-



Format of columns, sheets and rows is not important.
=IF(COUNTIF(AllNames!2:2,Employees!A:A)>0,"Yes","No")

I tried this and it shows if a name is found from AllNames table, but that's my top of idea that did not come further.

You could try using the following formula:


=MAP(A1:A34,LAMBDA(b,
 LET(a, TOCOL(Employees!A:A,1),
 TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(FILTER(AllNames!B2:G7,AllNames!A2:A7=b,"")=a,a,"")))))


But it is better to use Structured References aka Tables here instead of using the whole array. Therefore convert the each sources in sheets AllNames and Employees to tables.
=MAP(A1:A34,LAMBDA(b,
 LET(a, TOCOL(Employees,1),
 TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(FILTER(DROP(AllNames,,1),TAKE(AllNames,,1)=b,"")=a,a,"")))))


And if you don't have access to LAMBDA() helper functions could use the following:
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,XLOOKUP(INDEX(AllNames[[Name1]:[Name6]],MATCH(Calendar!A1,AllNames[Date],0),),Employees[Emp],Employees[Emp],"")),"")



This, kind sir, works like a charm.
Thank you very much!

Glad to know it worked. Thanks for sharing the valuable feedback, it helps to know!


Formula in I2:
=GROUPBY(TOCOL(IFS(B2:D4<>"",A2:A4),3),TOCOL(B2:D4,1),ARRAYTOTEXT,,0,,COUNTIF(F2:F4,TOCOL(B2:D4,1)))


A bit verbose:
=LET(
    comment_1, "Adjust the following to match max names per date",
    cols_with_names, 'All Names'!$B:$AA,
    dates, 'All Names'!$A2:INDEX('All Names'!$A:$A, COUNTA('All Names'!$A:$A)),
    current_employees, TOCOL(Employees!A:A, 1),
    HSTACK(
        dates,
        MAP(
            dates,
            LAMBDA(date_,
                LET(
                    names, TOCOL(INDEX(cols_with_names, ROW(date_), ), 1),
                    current, FILTER(names, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(names, current_employees))),
                    IFERROR(ARRAYTOTEXT(current), "No current employees")
                )
            )
        )
    )
)


